# Kerberos authentication for Git server?

Tags: git, kerberos, single-sign-on

I have a Git server, and I want to make it usable by all Kerberos-logged users.

eg: if a user has a valid Kerberos ticket, she can start pushing to Git without having to provide any username/password.

Is it even possible to do this with Git?
All I could find was [this](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Supporting-Kerberos-auth-over-HTTP-mod-auth-kerb-td6004737.html) old unanswered question on the Git mailing list (with http://), and [this](https://www.studentrobotics.org/trac/wiki/Kerberos/Git) project that says it is out-of-date (with git://).

Server is on Ubuntu 2012.10, but I could move it to Windows Server 2012 if necessary.
I can dictate which software to use on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of out-of-date project here; your best bet is to configure SSH to accept kerberos tickets for authentication -- it's straightforward and well documented across the internet.

If that doesn't meet your requirements for whatever reason, you could fall back to using [git-http-backend](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) to serve git over http{,s}, and then apache's [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) to authenticate access to that. I've had success with this, but it's fiddly to set up.

(mod_auth_kerb is libapache-mod-auth-kerb on ubuntu, git comes with git-http-backend)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the server user SSH with kerberos (just google for kerberos and SSH) and then git also will work with those kerberos users when you user git+ssh.